# Problem network WiFi WEP in Mac

Tags: terminal, network, wifi

The problem is: **It connects me to a WEP network but it does not allow me to enter the internet**, I enter the correct password (I know what it is) but it gives me the following error:

```
The "XXXX" WiFi network requires a WEP password.

The WEP security system is not considered secure. Connection error.

If this is your Wi-Fi network, configure the router to use the WPA2 (AES) security type for this network.
```

Postscript / PD: I don't have access to the router.

**How can I solve that?**

I am on another pc. I have installed a version of MacOSX Sierra in the Virtualbox. I am trying to analyze the connections to which I have access as I would do in a Windows "cmd" console but I don't know certain commands.

**I would like to translate this command to Mac terminal:**

```
>netsh wlan show profile 
>netsh wlan show profile name="XXXX" key="clear"
```

He tried the following commands but it doesn't work for me.[image]

Comment: Are you saying your running virtualbox on a Windows box then running macos in the virtual box.  That's a violation of the macOS copyright.